# automator applescript restart workflow

Tags: applescript, automator

I have an automator workflow. How can I make it restart the workflow in an `if` statement?

```
on run {input, parameters}

if (input as text) is "" then
    -- restart workflow
end if

return input
end run
```

Comment: any commands before/after `if`?

Comment: @wannik no commands before/after `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without AppleScript**

At the end of automator workflow, put `Loop`. (`Loop` is in `Library > Utilities`) `Loop` has an option `Ask to Continue`. If the user click `Continue`, Automator will restart the workflow. If not, the next process after the `Loop` will be executed.

**With AppleScript**

At the end of automator workflow, put `Run AppleScript` and `Loop`. Set the `Loop` option to `Loop automatically` and `Stop After` **1000** `times`. The AppleScript code is as follows.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if (input as text) is "" then
        tell me to quit
    end if
    return input
end run
```

The latter choice can repeat not more than 1000 times.